# PHP Variable name add 1

Tags: php, loops

I use a loop and 8 variables with almost the same name.

$date1,$date2,$date3,etc..

Now I want to do in the loop echo $date$i
Any idea how to achieve this ?

The PHP loop :

```
$i = 1;
while ($i < 8 ) {
echo $date$i;
$i++;
}
```

Comment: If you need to number your variables, then you'd be better using an array

Comment: concatenate it `$date.$i`

Comment: If yoy really need to use this structure, then use [Variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Use arrays instead of indexed variables.

Comment: or use the [eval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: The amount of times I write an answer and then as I go to post it, it's been disabled ... is infuriating! :P

Comment: @PeterSchneider Your comment is wrong.

Comment: @zan Your comment is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll use an `array` for that:

```
$data = array('x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', '1' , '2');
for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    echo $data[$i];
}
```

However if you for whatever reason need 8 variables (I can't see a reason), you need to do it like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    echo ${"data$i"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others before, a better way to go about this this would be to use arrays.  Anyways correct syntax for what you want to do would be

```
$i = 1;
while ($i < 8 ) {
echo ${"date$i"};
$i++;
}
```